# COMMIT not working in phpmyadmin (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, select, transactions, phpmyadmin, command-prompt

I've a mysql database with table `tbl_setting` with InnoDB type. Its autocommit is set to 1. I executed following queries in phpmyadmin.

```
begin;
INSERT INTO tbl_setting (setting_name) VALUES ('test');
commit;
```

While browsing from phpmyadmin, it is showing the desired result; But in command mode of Windows 8, with query `SELECT * FROM tbl_setting` it is not displaying the row I just inserted. I am needing to do commit in command mode to get the desired output. Shouldn't the database be updated automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research I found the problem. The autocommit in command mode was set 0; So, after executing `SET @@AUTOCOMMIT = 1;` query, the problem was solved.