# Hibernate cannot access data inserted by phpMyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, phpmyadmin

My question is about hibernate, actually I'm working on a Java EE application using hibernate and mysq.

Everything looks fine. but I still have one problem when I insert data via phpMyAdmin to my database, I cannot access them immediately via hibernate unless I started the server (tomcat) again.

Comment: Please post details about the phpMyAdmin update query, the Tomcat select query, and the DB connection details.

Comment: i did understand from some articles on the internet that its about hibernate second level cache , but i don't know how to fix it yet

Comment: Try searching for techniques to clear hibernate cache and this might help http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Cache.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that i've forgot to add **transaction.commit();** for every hibernate **session.get();** method, so somehow it keeps data in the cache.

```
public List<User> getAllUsers(User user) throws Exception {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.ne("idUser", user.getIdUser()));
            List<User> users = c.list();
            tx.commit();//i forget to add this

            return users;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback(); throw e;

        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your transaction in phpMyAdmin was not committed.

Try running this query in phpMyAdmin before running commands.

```
SET @@AUTOCOMMIT = 1;
```

Or running `commit;` at the end of your query.

Possible duplicate of:
[COMMIT not working in phpmyadmin (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330834/commit-not-working-in-phpmyadmin-mysql)

Comment: thank you for your answer, i did what you asked me to but it still not working, i can't access data from my java application unless i started tomcat again

Comment: I'm glad that my suggestion to commit your queries was helpful.